# java set.contains() gives false when set contains element?

Tags: java, set, equality

See snippet below out a junit test. An account has a set with with assignments. I want to remove an element from assignment when the contained city name equals 'Bladel'

```
Assignment toBeDeleted = null;
for (Assignment ass : account.getAssignments()) {
    if (ass.getCity().getName().equals("Bladel")) {
        toBeDeleted = ass;
        break;
    }
}
Assert.assertNotNull(toBeDeleted);
for (Assignment ass : account.getAssignments()) {
    logger.info(String.format("hash [%s] %d with [%s] %d",toBeDeleted.getCity().getName(), toBeDeleted.hashCode(), ass.getCity().getName(), ass.hashCode()));
    if (ass.equals(toBeDeleted)) {logger.info("found equal assignment"); }
    if (ass.hashCode() == toBeDeleted.hashCode()) {logger.info("found equal hash assignment"); }
    if (ass == toBeDeleted) { logger.info("it is == with"); }
}
Assert.assertTrue(account.getAssignments().contains(toBeDeleted));
```

But that fails so I replaced the `.remove()` with `.contains()` Stil failing. The log definitely shows that toBeDeleted is at some point equal to an element from the set:

```
2014-02-27 22:33:35 INFO  AssignmentDAOTest:134 - found equal assignment
2014-02-27 22:33:35 INFO  Assignment:66 - for assignment + Bladel result is 2121952
2014-02-27 22:33:35 INFO  Assignment:66 - for assignment + Bladel result is 2121952
2014-02-27 22:33:35 INFO  AssignmentDAOTest:135 - found equal hash assignment
2014-02-27 22:33:35 INFO  AssignmentDAOTest:136 - it is == with
```

What is going wrong? I thought that the `remove()` and `contains()` matches when `equals()` returns true.

Per Comment:
Account is Hibernate mapped java class and the population of the set is in ths unittest left to Hibernate.

```
public class Account {
    ....
@OneToMany(mappedBy="account", fetch=FetchType.LAZY, cascade={CascadeType.ALL})
public Set<Assignment> getAssignments() {return assignments;}
public void setAssignments(Set<Assignment> asgmnts) {
    logger.info("setting assignments");
    assignments = asgmnts;
}
```

Comment: Can you show your `Assignment` class?

Comment: Are you using a TreeSet ?

Comment: What type is `account.getAssignments()` ?

Comment: Set is from Hibernate @oneToMany. I'll update question

Answer (score 1):

In case you are using a TreeSet for storing your assignments then you need to override compareTo() method in your Assignment class or provide a custom comparator for comparing the Assignment objects.

Here is the text from javadoc  :[link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html)

> Note that the ordering maintained by a set (whether or not an explicit comparator is provided) must be consistent with equals if it is to correctly implement the Set interface. (See Comparable or Comparator for a precise definition of consistent with equals.) This is so because the Set interface is defined in terms of the equals operation, but a TreeSet instance performs all element comparisons using its compareTo (or compare) method, so two elements that are deemed equal by this method are, from the standpoint of the set, equal. The behavior of a set is well-defined even if its ordering is inconsistent with equals; it just fails to obey the general contract of the Set interface.

Comment: @ZouZou thats true too !!